# Error in script sending automatic birthday wish to a registered user in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the script of sending automatic e-mail for a given date. I have already set up the cron job to execute this once a day for a given time. But it is not working. Can anyone show me the error here. I'm really new to this.
What I'm really supposed to do is to send an automatic email to a user on their birthday

```
   <?php
    $host="mysql117.000webhost.com/";//hostname
    $username="abc";//mysql_username
    $password="123";//mysql_password
    $dbname="abc";//Database name
    $tbl_name="customer_info";//table name

    $date = date("2005-09-23"); //here my date format in my DB is 2010-09-30
    $link = mysqli_connect('$host','$username','$password','$dbname');
    if($link && mysqli_select_db('$dbname', $link))
    {
  $grabBday = "SELECT b_day,DATE_FORMAT(b_day,'2015-%m-%d') FROM customer_info where b_day = '2002-09-24'";
        //here it will take the name of the person whose bday is on a particular date,I just hard coded this date to check  if this is working
        if($rs = mysqli_query($link, $grabBday))
        {
            while(mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
            {
                mail('abc92@yahoo.com', 'HAPPY BIRTHDAY', 'Many Happy Returns of the day');
            }
        }
    }  ?>
```

Comment: "It is not working" is a bit vague, could you be more precise?

Comment: Can you please check DATATYPE of b_day field in database?

Comment: well actually as I have set it up to execute within a given time period I didn't recieve any mail regarding this.

Comment: I just change my DATATYPE to date in the database

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing logical difference as you are searching where b_day=$date where $date='2015-09-23' but dob can be '2002-09-23' or '1997-09-23' etc. so you will not get desired output, so you can change your query as per below if everything other than it is fine.

```
SELECT * FROM 
tbl_name 
WHERE CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),DATE_FORMAT(b_day,'-%m-%d')) = $date
```

Comment: Thank u soo much! I'll try this out

Comment: I changed my script as above . I'm still waiting for it execute. I'll let you know if it works. Thank you very much

Comment: Same problem I'm still not getting any e-mail. I set up the cron job to execute this in every 5 mins but still it's not sending any e-mail

Comment: first try this query on any query browser and check if you are getting desired results....as there can be issue related with date format....if query is providing results then you can try just "select email from ....." instead of "select * from...." may be it helps you as I can help you in DB but not much in php...

Comment: The query is not working. I tired this but it is not selecting any value for this query. Can you please help me with this?  this is '-%m-%d' working now

Comment: this will work if your b_date data type will be date. if it is varchar then you have to make it desired date format in different way like concat(year(curdate()),'-',mid(b_date,6,2),'-',right(b_date,2))=$date etc....

Comment: my data type in database is as 'DATE'

Comment: "SELECT b_date,DATE_FORMAT(b_date,'2015-%m-%d') FROM mytable LIMIT 1;" please share what result you are getting by this.

Comment: Yes now it is selecting some data from database. I have some records as '0000-00-00' as very fist records and it's selecting that perticular record. When I increase the LIMIT to 5 then it selects top most values from db.(2010-09-23) is there as my 2nd record and it includes for the selected 5 records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90435/discussion-between-zafar-malik-and-akisha).